# AppLovin Integration

Tags: java, android, applovin

I'm following AppLovin tutorial on their site, but I don't understand if I only have to write:

```
private void ShowInterstitial() {
   AppLovinInterstitialAd.show(ActivityMain.this);
}
```

and call this method everytime I want or if I have to write something else.
With the show command AppLovin automatically preload another Interstitial after one is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would only need to call the show method to display an ad.  Our SDK will automatically manage the caching of interstitial ads for you and load the next ad.

For further assistance, please email support@applovin.com